# Изменить значение без изменения страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Допустим, есть php - код, который после выполнения выдаёт определённое значение на странице. При обновлении страницы значение меняется. Как бы сделать, чтобы это значение изменялось без обновления страницы? Думаю, организовать это с помощью js. Выносил код в отдельный документ, а далее подгружал его на нужную страницу. Но, в ответ приходила либо пустота, либо оставалось первоначальное значение после некоторых танцев. Ссылка на подгружаемый файл - правильная. Ибо если написать там что-то другое - подгружается значение. А если php - код сразу находился на нужной странице, то всё нормально. Но требуется обновление страницы.
Подгружал так:

```
setInterval(function() {
$("#azaza").load('azaza.php');
        }, 1000);
```

Так же, есть ссылка имеющая `id = "azaza"`. Как бы, то что находится между `<a>` и его закрывающим должно изменяться. К самому тегу уже задан `href`, имеющий ссылку. Если это важно.

Comment: самое первое, что рекомендую сделать - открыть консоль разработки (F12 или Ctrl+Shift+J в хроме, firebug  в firefox) и посмотреть сетевую активность. Там должны быть запросы каждую секунду. Плюс, можно посмотреть, что там приходит. Это даст пищу для размышлений.

Comment: Дайте ссыль на исходник azaza.php